# How to create bundle / combo discount logic in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, dictionary, multidimensional-array, data-structures

I am trying to solve a question for interview preparation. I am struggling to find the right data structure and logic to solve this.

The question is as follows

There are inputs  array of the format: `["date, item"]`. For example:

```
[["10212021", popcorn], ["10222021", popcorn], ["10212021", soda],["10212021", popcorn],["10212021", soda]]
```

On the same day if there are popcorn and soda both purchased, then it costs 9 dollars as a bundled price. else soda is 2.5 dollars, popcorn is 8 dollars.

You need to calculate the total price based on these criteria and return that as output.

My initial train of thought

1. Have each item tuple - date and item in a hashtable or dictionary
2. if a corresponding item exists with the same date for the combo apply
   discount
3. deduct combo price from total

I am a beginner in JS please advise.

Comment: Note: that input should use a string for the item: `["10212021", 'popcorn']`.

Comment: I would create an object (dictionary) using the dates as keys, and an array as the value. Iterate over the input adding the item into the array if the date matches. Then you can iterate over the object and if a date has two items in the array you can add $9 to the total, otherwise the non-discounted price of the item.

Comment: Thanks for the edit and advice Andy. let me try with some code on this approach.

Comment: That's a good idea, and if you run into problems come back and write a question using your code as a [mcve] so we can help debug it. As it stands this question is a bit too broad for SO. Welcome to SO, btw. You might find reading the site [help section](https://stackoverflow.com/help) useful when it comes to [asking a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and this [question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist).